# Multiple Spark Sessions in single JVM

Tags: apache-spark

I have a query regarding creating multiple spark sessions in one JVM.  `SPARK-2243` says that creating multiple Sparkcontexts is not supported. Is it true for the SparkSession in Spark 2.0 as well. I also read about the `cloneSession` method in SparkSession API, which allows creating an identical copy of a `SparkSession` and share the underlying `SparkContext` between the two sessions. Does this mean that there can be multiple SparkSessions in one JVM?

Comment: Read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19540, Yes you can have multiple session but context will be same.